# Software that can hide my face in a video

Tags: windows, gratis, video, video-editing, privacy

I would like to record myself performing an athletic activity, and I plan on uploading those videos to receive feedback on my technique.  However, before I upload the videos, I want to edit them to hide my face.

Is there any free software for Windows that will let me tell it where my face is, and then it can either black out or put a mosaic on my face that follows my face around for the entire video?

Answer (score 1):

A free open source program available for Windows, Mac and Linux known as [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/download/) will likely allow you to accomplish your goal.

A quick search shows that it contains a feature called [automasking](http://write.flossmanuals.net/kdenlive/advanced-video-effects/). Accompanying that feature is a tracking function that provides the movement of the pixelation or blocking you reference.

There are other resources than the single link I've provided, including a number of YouTube videos. Using the search terms "automask kdenlive" will allow you to select the tutorial and reference material you prefer.